# Updating a non-bound field in a form with a record source

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form with a record source of `SELECT [AccountRunInProgress] from [AccountRunSummary]`. The form contains a text box with a date which is used to apply a filter on the above record source, based on the month and year (defined as two separate fields in the AccountRunSummary table).

The other field in the form is a check box bound to the AccountRunInProgress field. When ticked, the OnClick event for this box updates a date field called RunProgressStartDate in the AccountRunSummary table with the current date and time.

**I then get a Write Conflict error when closing the form** - almost certainly because I am trying to update the table via the OnClick event while using the table as the record source at the same time, despite not binding the date fields. The date is updated in the table but not the boolean.

What is the best practice for working around this? I thought about adding RunProgressStartDate as a hidden bound text box in the form and adding it to the record source, but I'm fairly sure that will cause more problems rather than less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track.

You can't edit a record through the bound form and with an Update query (in VBA) at the same time.

IMO the best solution is indeed to add `RunProgressStartDate` to the record source and as hidden control to the form.

Then (important!) set the value of this control in the OnClick event, don't write the table with an Update query:

```
Me!RunProgressStartDate.Value = Date()
```

and both fields (checkbox and date) will be saved when the record is saved.

Comment: Ah perfect. I was thrown off by this solution at first because I was still getting the same errors, I assumed that it wasn't possible to update the value of a bound field. Must have still had the update statement running in the OnClick event without realising. Thank you!